# GITLAB: Cannot debug Nodejs Mocha test failures

Tags: node.js, express, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running following environment:

```
GIT + Self hosted Gitlab
Node.js + Express
Mocha ( for tests )
Winston ( for logging)
```

The command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/mocha
```

runs fine on local system **for all branches**. But the same fails on gitlab on multiple branches (on one of the branches, it works).

All my node.js exceptions goes to **logs/exceptions.log** file.
On local system, I can view the content of exceptions.log to figure out what is wrong, but on Gitlab => PipeLines, I am not able to view this file.

**If I can see the exceptions.log file content on Gitlab, I can figure out what is wrong**

Here is my **.gitlab-ci** file:

```
image: node:6

services:
   - postgres:latest

variables:
   POSTGRES_DB: test
   POSTGRES_USER: nodeapp
   POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ""

stages:
   # Install necessary dependencies.
   - build
      # Run tests
   - test
      # Clean up dependencies if build fails.
   - build_cleanup

cache:
    key: XYZ_Cache_03_05_2018
paths:
    - node_modules/

# Job: Build
# Checks & Installs dependencies.
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    # check & install apt-get
    - 'which apt-get || ( apt-get update )'
    # check & install node
    - 'which node || ( apt-get -y install nodejs --silent )'
    # check & install npm
    - 'which npm || ( apt-get -y install npm --silent )'
   allow_failure: false

# Job: Test
# Run tests against our application
# If this fails, we do not deploy
 test:
   stage: test
   script:
     - npm install
     - npm install -y --global bower --silent
     - bower install --allow-root --silent
     - npm install --global gulp-cli
     - npm install mocha
     - ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha
 allow_failure: false


 build_cleanup:
    stage: build_cleanup
    script:
       - rm -rf node_modules
       when: on_failure
```